# font-size de un textarea se achica cuando se completa por el usuario

Tags: css3, formularios, textarea

tengo un formulario con input y textarea (como cualquiera) y le aumente el font-size para que se lea más fácil, el problema es que cuando uno comienza a rellenar los campos se escribe todo muuuucho más chico y no se por que??

Paso código para que vean que error estoy cometiendo...

```css
form textarea,
form textarea::placeholder,
form textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

form input,
form input::placeholder,
form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<form action="confFormularioBriefSeg.php" id="form2" name="form2" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="octava" class="brief boton" name="octava" placeholder="Nombre o denominación">
  <textarea name="novena" id="novena" class="textarea boton" placeholder="Descripción breve(dicho “en criollo” para entender el servicio a comunicar)"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Tienes un punto de mas en el `font-size` del `input`.

Comment: ahi lo corregí en la pregunta, gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mejor forma de lograr lo que quieres es usando `font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit;` asi:

```css
form {
  font-size: 2em;
}

form textarea,
form textarea::placeholder,
form textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  height: 70px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

form input,
form input::placeholder,
form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<form action="confFormularioBriefSeg.php" id="form2" name="form2" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="octava" class="brief boton" name="octava" placeholder="Nombre o denominación">
  <textarea name="novena" id="novena" class="textarea boton" placeholder="Descripción breve(dicho “en criollo” para entender el servicio a comunicar)"></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Buenisimo! muchas gracias. Una ultima consulta: porque sucede eso? lo de tomar un tamaño de placeholder y otro al llenar el campo...

Comment: lo probe y no toma los form{font-size: 2em;} por lo que con el "inherit" queda el placeholder chiquito (del mismo tamaño que cuando el usuario rellena el campo)

Comment: estaba perfecta tu recomendación, el error era que había asignado un valor de "font-size: 0.6em" a la clase del input sin darme cuenta y por eso no tomaba las configuraciones "inherit". Lo positivo es que aprendí un nuevo comando que desconocía. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Solo borra el punto que tiene el `.1.5em`, le agregue `4` puntos mas al `em` del `textarea` para que tengan el mismo tamaño la letra

```css
form textarea,
form textarea::placeholder,
form textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

form input,
form input::placeholder,
form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<form action="confFormularioBriefSeg.php" id="form2" name="form2" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="octava" class="brief boton" name="octava" placeholder="Nombre o denominación"><br><br>
  <textarea name="novena" id="novena" class="textarea boton" placeholder="Descripción breve(dicho “en criollo” para entender el servicio a comunicar)"></textarea>
</form>
```